# getting marathi data from request.getParameter

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding, getparameter

In my request `Queryparameter="आकुर्डी"`. When I'm trying following

```
String strstring = request.getParameter("Queryparameter");
```

it gives `"à¤à¤à¥à¤°à¥à¤¡à¥"` while I want the string `"आकुर्डी"`.

How to get it? What is the problem here?

Comment: Please provide proper tags so that appropriate audience are addressed to guide you with different approaches.

Comment: what is your page-encoding? IIRC, look at the meta tag of your page where you can specify the encoding. what is it? utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused because you used a different character encoding to parse the request parameters than the client is using to construct the request parameters. For best compatibility with all characters known in the human world, you need to ensure that both the client and server is using the `UTF-8` character encoding throughout all layers.

If it is a `GET` request, then you need to configure the servletcontainer/appserver to parse the request URI as `UTF-8`. You didn't tell which one you're using, but if it is for example Tomcat, then you can do so by setting the `URIEncoding` attribtue of the [`<Connector>` element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) to `UTF-8`:

```
<Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

If you're using a different servletcontainer/appserver, then you need to consult its documentation how to configure the character encoding of the request URI.

If it is a `POST` request, then you need to instruct the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to parse the request body as `UTF-8` using [`HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) before collecting the request parameters.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

For more background information and more solutions in other areas you would need to take into account as well (such as generating the response as `UTF-8` and instructing the client to use `UTF-8`, so that you can keep it all uniform), you may find this blog useful: [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: @Calm Storm: Not in JSP/Servlet yet, it's ISO-8859-1. In ASP.NET it is. In PHP it's far from easy/efficient.